# PHPmailer sanitazion/validation a second oppinion.

Tags: php

I wonder if someone could give me some pointers to my PHPmailer Process file and see if they find any misstakes or things that I have missed in the validation/sanitation of the data.
Any input would be most wellcome!

```
<?php
//includes
require_once('func/mail/mailcon/config-info.php');
require_once('include/class.phpmailer.php');
//Sanitazion and cleanup.
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

$entries = array();
$errors = array();
// Escape and extract all the post values
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $entries[$key] = sanitize($value);
}

// Get a set of variable variables for easier use
foreach ($entries as $key => $value) {
    ${$key} = $value;
}
//validation
//contact_Name
if (empty($contact_Name)) {
$errors['contact_Name'] = 'Detta fält måste fyllas i.';
}
elseif (mb_strlen($contact_Name, 'UTF-8') > 50) {
$errors['contact_Name'] = 'Detta namn är för långt, får inte vara över 50 tecken.';
}
//contact_Foretag.
if (mb_strlen($contact_Foretag, 'UTF-8') > 50) {
$errors['contact_Foretag'] = 'Detta företagsnamn är för långt, får inte vara över 50 tecken';
}
//contact_Email
if (empty($contact_Email)) {
$errors['contact_Email'] = 'Detta fält måste fyllas i.';
}
elseif (!(filter_var($contact_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))) {
$errors['contact_Email'] = 'Fyll i en giltig E-post address.';
}
//contact_Subject
if (empty($contact_Subject)) {
$errors['contact_Subject'] = 'Detta fält måste fyllas i.';
}
elseif (mb_strlen($contact_Subject, 'UTF-8') > 50) {
$errors['contact_Subject'] = 'Detta ämne är för långt, får inte vara över 50 tecken.';
}
//contact_Message
if (empty($contact_Message)) {
$errors['contact_Message'] = 'Detta fält måste fyllas i.';
}
elseif (mb_strlen($contact_Message, 'UTF-8') > 5000) {
$errors['contact_Message'] = 'Detta meddeoande är för långt, får inte vara över 5000 tecken.';
}

//If no errors
if (empty($errors)) {

$formOK = true;
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
  $mail->IsSMTP();
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
  $mail->Host = MAIL_HOST;
  $mail->Port = MAIL_PORT;
  $mail->Username = MAIL_USER;
  $mail->Password = MAIL_PASS;
  $mail->SetFrom($contact_Email, $contact_Name);
  $mail->Subject = "$contact_Subject";
  $mail->Body = "Your received the following message from $contact_Mame ($contact_Foretag)   <$contact_Email>:\r\n\r\n$contact_Message";
  $mail->AddAddress(MAIL_ADDR);
  $mail->Send();

 } catch (PHPMailerException $e) {
 header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
        echo "Exception occurred: ".$e->errorMessage();
        exit();
 }
}
else {
    $formOK = false;
}

//if this is not an ajax request  
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest'){  
    session_start();  
    $return_data = array(
        'formOK'  => $formOK,
        'errors'  => $errors,
        'entries' => $entries
    );
    $_SESSION['return_data']  = $return_data;
    header('Location: ' . BASE_URL);
    exit();
} 
} //First 
else {
header('Location: ' . BASE_URL);
exit();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

and welcome to CodeReview!

Here's a few things:

- You have a lot of pointless comments

  - ("includes": The includes are the next line. We see them; no need to tell us.)
- Indent block content.

  - Whenever you enter an if block, indent it.
  - Same for while/for/functions/classes/methods/etc
- Your variable-variable loop is equivalent to `extract`.
- `extract` tends to be a bad idea (the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) has various warnings)

  - It pollutes the scope
  - You no longer know what variables are and are not defined unless you strictly control what is inside of the array (which you don't for $_POST)
  - Users can clobber *your* values, meaning there are certain security implications.
  - Can be mitigated with options to extract, but still a problem
  - In short, there are a few situations where extract is convenient and a decent idea; this is not one of them.
  - use `$_POST[...]` or `$entries[...]` directly.
- Variable variables are also a bad idea.

  - Variable variables scream "What I really need is an array!"
  - You already have an array :)
- Don't sanitize content until you're actually ready to put it into the context for which you're sanitizing it.

  - For example, & is a special character in HTML (in some contexts). DBs do not care about it. Nor do plain text emails. Or email subjects. Or... infinite things.
  - Rule of thumb: sanitize at the last possible moment.
  - You can also take the raw value and process it, but you can't always do the reverse.
- Be careful with empty() on strings

  - empty($var) === (isset($var) && $var)
  - Implicit bool rules are *very* odd in PHP though. In particular, the string "0" can get you.
  - I doubt `0` should be a valid email content, but just throwing it out there in case it gets you in the future.
- Invert your conditions and you'll see that you can bail early:

  - if (...) { /* huge block */ } else { /* redirect */ exit; }*
  - Instead you could do if (!...) { / redirect */ exit; }
  - Now your entire file doesn't have to be indented one step.
  - This is similar to the concept of returning early, though it tends to be less applicable to files (redirection is one of the few justified uses of `exit` in web site PHP)
- You have a typo of `$contact_Mame` rather than `$contact_Name` in your email content
- Be careful with 500 errors. IE has a minimum length limit where if your response is less than some number of bytes, IE 'helpfully' replaces your content with its own.

  - Also, I'm torn on how I feel about this being a 500 response. It's not really an internal error so much as just an exception.
  - Internal errors implies a major mess up to me like Apache is pissed off, or a E_FATAL PHP error.
- You should probably log the email failing to send. You could just use something like `trigger_error` if you want to go the simple route.
- `$formOK` is gaurenteed to be `$formOK === empty($errors)`. This means you could just use `empty($errors)` in it's place.
- I tend to use only strict equalities with strings these days. If you're comparing something to a string, you're sure 99.9% of the time that it's a string. If you're sure it should be a string, might as well use a strict check.

  - There are situations where loose string comparisons are still quite handy though.
- I would use a GET or POST variable to signify AJAX rather than checking a header.

  - Headers can be spoofed.
  - Testing becomes easier.
  - No potential browser/JS library compatibility issues
- `$mail->Subject = "$contact_Subject";` is (functionally) equivalent to `$mail->Subject = (string) $contact_Subject;`

  - You know it's already a string, so no need for the cast.
  - Just do `$mail->Subject = $contact_Subject`.
  - Also, I wouldn't use `"$var"` as a cast. I would stick with explict casts (`(string) $var`).

Comment: This is an awsome answer! Thx @Corbin

Comment: Corbin I looked at your answer and did as you suggested, but the one thing I still don´t get is " would use a GET or POST variable to signify AJAX rather than checking a heade"  could you elaborate on it a bit?